# Adding a:focus outline to all links

Tags: html, css

I've set the following default styles for my main site links:

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #000;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
    outline: 0;
}
```

When styling other links, I've followed the same pattern, e.g:

```
.button {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
.button:visited,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
    color: #fff;
}
.button:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Is it necessary to include focus outline styles for other links or will the browser fall back to my defaults? I understand that having correct focus styles will aid accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `:focus` pseudo class on your 'classed' links should not be different from your main links, there is no need to declare it again.